# Why does C++ array creation cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, segmentation-fault, openmp

I have a program that needs an array of `set<vector<bool>>`. For the small value of array size, the program works well. When the program runs into large array size, it exits with exit code -1073741571.

So, I debug the code and find when it occurs. Below is the simplest code that reproduces my error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    set<vector<bool>> C[43309];
}
```

Values smaller than 43309 cause no error. I try debugging and it shows

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff0d17ca99 in ntdll!memset () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
[Thread 17616.0x3f64 exited with code 3221225725]
[Thread 17616.0x342c exited with code 3221225725]
[Inferior 1 (process 17616) exited with code 030000000375]
```

I don't really understand what is the problem. I have tried searching similar questions but still I don't get it. I also tried running it in [ideone](https://ideone.com/nbyXR1) and it works fine. So, I think it might be related to my IDE, eclipse. (not sure)

Comment: Do you compile your program with OpenMP support? OpenMP control thread stack sizes via [`OMP_STACKSIZE` environment variable](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html#x293-20620006.6). The default value on your system may be small. The (byte)size of `C` is quite large: https://rextester.com/OQD46795.

Comment: `sizeof(std::set<std::vector<bool>>)` is (or can be) [48 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/ucxOMZ) on x86-64. `48 * 43309 = 2078832`, just under 2 MiB that you are trying to allocate on the stack. This is pretty clearly a stack overflow. Don't allocate megabytes worth of stuff on the stack, that's not what it's for.

Comment: Yes. The original problem use OpenMP. It might be the problem.

Comment: @nanda I am not sure whether the main thread's stack size is also controlled by `OMP_STACKSIZE`. However, even if not, the default stack size of your program/process seems not to be high enough to store `C` in it. You can either increase the stack size or better to allocate the array dynamically (e.g., by `std::vector<std::set<std::vector<bool>>> C(43309)`.

Comment: I am new to C++. So, I might be wrong. I think what you are suggesting is instead of array, you want me to use vector. Why doesn't it casue problem?

Comment: @nanda Since `vector` allocates the memory space for its elements on the _heap_, while (non-static/automatic-local) arrays on the _stack_. Stacks have usually a very limited capacity.

Comment: `std::vector` itself is only 48 bytes (implementation specific, can be few bytes more/less on some platforms), and memory for elements stored in vector is allocated from the "heap" area (dynamic allocation with `new/delete`). So if you do `main... { std::vector<...> x; /* add many elements to x here */ }` then the vector control meta data are in the "stack" area, but the many elements added to `x` are in "heap" area. Generally the stack area is couple of megabytes only, as it is expected to be used for local variables and call stack, heap is the "what OS provides" free memory.

Comment: Thank, I think I got a general idea about what you mean. I will try more googling about these and also about OMP_STACKSIZE.  Can you write it as an answer, so I can close that question?

Comment: you can also move the `C` into global variables, outside of `main` function scope, that will make that memory space reserved upon loading the executable time, and fixed for the whole lifetime of the run. Generally usage of global variables if frowned upon because of this (high memory usage even when app does not need the variable any more), difficult unit testing, often code logic gets complex and difficult to reason about as it depends on global state which is easy to change from anywhere in the code, the variable size is fixed at compilation time, etc... but in certain cases it's an option.

Comment: google more about memory allocators, what is stack/heap, sections in executable, and initialized/uninitialized data... being aware of where your values reside is IMO very important, and feels to me like it is often(?) neglected a bit in various tutorials/courses, focusing more on syntax and algorithms without explaining where that storage space for all those millions of numbers comes from (and why certain space is more limited than other).

Comment: @Ped7g Noted and thanks. The array size will be defined at runtime based on previous calculations. So, I guess it might not be an option for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set<vector<bool>> C[43309];
```

allocates `43309` copies of `std::set` on the stack. On windows the default stack size is normally 1MB. Judging by your observed results your implementation's `std::set` probably uses around 24 bytes each resulting in your array using `1,039,392` bytes which is more than the available stack memory.

Stacks are small on all platforms, Mac and Linux typically have 8MB stacks. They are only designed to be used for small allocations of local variables, function parameters, saved registers etc. Large allocations should be done on the heap.

The simplest way to do this is using `std::vector`, it manages the heap allocation for you:

```
auto C = vector<set<vector<bool>>>(43309);
```